# ng-repeat with some conditions

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a JSON which has the property `prizes` which in some cases is like this:

```
"prize" : {
  "Firstyear" : {
    "first" : 3000,
    "second" : 2000,
    "total" : 5000
     },
  "Secondyear" : {
    "first" : 3000,
    "second" : 2000,
    "total" : 5000
     },
  "Thirdyear" : {
    "first" : 3000,
    "second" : 2000,
    "total" : 5000
     },
   "total" : 15000
  },
```

but in some cases, it's like this:

```
"prize" : {
    "first" : 4000,
    "second" : 3000,
    "third" : 2000,
    "total" : 9000
},
```

How do I `ng-repeat` over these?

Comment: in any case you cannot use ng-repeat, because its just a object

Comment: use for (var key in prize) which get the keys of your object and do your if condition as u wish

Comment: Could you do a jsfiddle for demo purpose? @FadiAboMsalam

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do ng-repeat over Object unless you want to get the key and value of an object. I guess you need the following.

**DEMO**

```js
var uniqcApp = angular.module('uniqueApp',[]);
uniqcApp.controller('testController', function ($scope){
   $scope.data = {"prize" : {
    "first" : 4000,
    "second" : 3000,
    "third" : 2000,
    "total" : 9000
}};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="uniqueApp">
<div class="row" ng-controller="testController">
 <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.prize">
    <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```